# given "N" find p & q such that p+q=N and p*q is maximum

Tags: math

I need the logic/idea behind a rough solution I have come up with.

The problem is:

Given N, where `1<=N<=1000000`
Now i need to find two numbers p and q such that `p + q = N && p * q = maximum.`

I chose to use this `(((N+1)/2)*((N/2)));` which basically gives me the maximum product with the minimum sum. But I am kind of interested in the proof of this logic.

Any help or leads?

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long uint;
unsigned long calc(uint);

int main(void) {
    short i = 0;
    uint k = 0;
    scanf("%i", &i);
    while(i--) {
        scanf("%lu", &k);
        printf("%lu\n", calc(k));
    }
    return 0;
}

uint calc(uint k){
    return (((k+1)/2)*((k/2)));
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a mathematical question, not a programming question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a mathematical question, not a programming question.

Comment: While the question may contain code, the essence of the question appears to be off-topic because it is about [math.se].

Comment: Hint: work out the differentiation of `p*(N-p)` with respect to `p`, then find its roots, then you'll find out where the local maximum and minimum is

Comment: Calculus will give you the answer.

Comment: Given a fixed circumference of 2N, find the rectangle with integer sides p and q and maximal area. This formulation of your problem should be quite well-known.

Answer (score 3):

Let

```
f(p) = p * (N - p) = p * N - p ^ 2
```

Then:

```
f'(p) = N - 2 * p
f''(p) = - 2
```

Since `f''(p) < 0`, simply solving for `f'(p) = 0` gives us a local *maxima*.

```
When f'(p) = 0, 
p = N / 2
=> q = N / 2
```

You also need to test the end-points `f(0)` and `f(N)`, but both of these evaluate to zero, so our maxima is the global maximum.

Note: This is basically saying that of all the rectangles of a certain perimeter, the square has the largest area.